# What kind of object is data.frame(matrix(...)) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

What does this code do?

```
xy <-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow=100000, dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
```

Is there any other way of getting the same result without using the matrix function?

Answer (score 2):

The matrix is converted into a data.frame with column names X and Y.

You can always run the code yourself and call `str(xy)` to see the "structure" of the object.

```
> str(xy)
'data.frame':   100000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Y: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

This tells you `xy` is a data.frame with 100,000 rows and 2 columns.  The columns are named X and Y and the first few elements are logical `NA`s (they all are, but `str` only prints the first few).

If you want to skip the matrix part, just create the data.frame directly:

```
xy <- data.frame( X = rep(NA, 1e5), Y = rep(NA, 1e5))
```

Comment: what does 1e6 stand for here?

Comment: 1 times 10 to the 5th power.  ie, the number with a 1 and five 0s.

Comment: using the above code, takes way longer run time though

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: Neither the code in your question nor the code in my answer should take more than 0.001 seconds to run.

Comment: I guess that if this stage is what's causing a bottleneck (wink :p) you could always use `structure` to save a few nanoseconds. If this is being done for preallocation, one advantage of the `data.frame` or `structure` approach is that you could specify the `NA` type for each column if that's required.